# Git: Creating alias for "add --update TOPLEVEL_DIR"?

Tags: configuration, git-add, git, git-alias

I often find myself typing

```
git add -u
```

with the intention of adding everything that is modified but tracked in the *whole* repository. However, it gets annoying and tedious when I'm in a subdirectory. For example if all my modifications are in `src/` but I'm currently in the `test/util` directory, then I need to type

```
git add -u ../..
```

which is error-prone and slow (because I need to compute the number of `../` in my head).

I would like to create a git alias `au` such that it automatically detects the toplevel (usually, the first ancestor directory in the path that contains the `.git` directory). It doesn't have to be perfectly portable, since I use git from `bash`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to detect the top-level.
You can type in any subfolder:

```
git add -u :/
```

This is short for:

```
git add -u :(top)
```

See [git glossary](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary):

> A pathspec that begins with a colon : has special meaning. In the short form, the leading colon : is followed by zero or more "magic signature" letters (which optionally is terminated by another colon :), and the remainder is the pattern to match against the path.
>
> **top**: The magic word top (magic signature: `/`) makes the pattern match from the root of the working tree, even when you are running the command from inside a subdirectory.